Как расширить video widget в elementor?
Хочу написать свой виджет для элементора. С базовым примером ознакомился. Получилось зарегистрировать виджет, category и controls. Теперь хочу расширить Widget_Video. То есть просто добавить группу контролов туда и немного своего html. Не нашел как это правильно сделать в документации, поэтому попробовал в методе render моего виджета вызвать new Widget_Video(). Сontrols из Widget_Video добавились и ко мне в виджет, но самого видео не вижу на странице, хотя могу вибирать src для видео и прочее.
Нет ли какого-то метода типа get_controls(); и get_html(); чтобы получить все controls что есть у родителя и всю html разметку? Или надо просто вызвать parent::register_controls()?
class MyVideo extends Widget_Video {
protected function register_controls() {
        parent::register_controls();
        $this->start_controls_section('content_section');
        $this->add_group_control(
            Group_Control_Background::get_type(),
            [
                'name' => 'background of controls',
                'label' => __( 'Background', MY_WIDGET_PLUGIN_DOMAIN ),
                'types' => [ 'classic', 'gradient' ],
                'selector' => '{{WRAPPER}} .My-widget-wrapper-video',
            ]
        );
}

А html как из родителя получить?
